# Check if a checkbox is checked from JPS file

Tags: java, jsp

```
boolean flag_outlook ;
            String stringoutlook = request.getParameter("Send_outlook");
            if (stringoutlook != null)
                flag_outlook = true;
            else
                flag_outlook = false;



            String dataStartAppoiment = connect.timeFormatForDatabase(dayformat,Integer.parseInt( timefromedit));
            String dataEndAppoiment = connect.timeFormatForDatabase(dayformat, Integer.parseInt(timefromedit)+1);


            if(flag_outlook=true)
            {
                Apppoiment send = new Apppoiment();
                send.Appoiment(dataStartAppoiment, dataEndAppoiment,ContentCell);
            }
```

Checkbox from JSP look like this

```
<input type="checkbox"  name="Send_outlook" >
```

I try to execut a piece of code, if a checkbox is checked (up is my code) but is not working properly, every time my flag is true. I can't understand where is my mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your flag is always `true` is because in your `if-statement` you say:

```
if(flag_outlook = true)
```

That should be:

```
if(flag outlook == true)
```

Your problem is you're assigning in stead of comparing.

Comment: @Silviu I'm not exactly sure how `request.getParameter` works, but can your `string_outlook` actually be `null` or is it just empty?

Comment: If a the checkbox is checked, return a value what is retained by the "request.getParameter"  and passed to  "stringoutlook "

Comment: Someone else posted `request.getParameterValue`, but he removed his answer. Perhaps that's more what you're looking for? Also, your checkbox doesn't actually have a `value`.

Comment: <input type="checkbox" id="Send_outlook" name="Send_outlook" value="on" > I tried to give a value for the checkbox, again still not working